# Android OkHttp3 and Spring.io Post Multipart Data

Tags: java, android, spring, post, multipartform-data

I try to post multipart data to my server, but it won't work. My Server is build with the spring.io framework and my client are an android device.

if I tried with an external rest client, all worked fine. But in my android device, there got an error.

Here is what the server server will do:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public EntryImage uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestParam("entry_id") int entryId,
                              @RequestParam("sub_title") String subTitle,
                              @RequestParam("uploader") long uploader) {
// here is the logic...
}
```

and here is what I do in android. I Use okhttp3 to query http requests:

```
public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

File file = ImageHelper.getBitmapFile(NewEntryActivity.this, IMAGE.getImage());

                        FormBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                                .add("entry_id", String.valueOf(entryContract.getEntry_id()))
                                .add("uploader", "1")
                                .add("sub_title", "-")
                                .build();

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", "file", RequestBody.create(mediaType, file))
                .addPart(formParams)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
```

when I enqueue this request, I get an error-code 400 with the message "Required int parameter 'entry_id' is not present"

what do I wrong? How can I post form data from android to spring service?

I already tried to set the "RequestParam"-Types to String (cause in OkHttp I only can add strings to the formBody) but I get the same error.

Comment: Did you tried something obvious like adding FormDataPart with your parameters(not only a file) to the MultipartBody.Builder

Comment: @Selvin, okay that worked (crazy). I followed up the OkHttpSample from here https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostForm.java. maybe it don't work with multipart-data. Could you please set up your comment to an answer, so I can accept it? (and please put a small code snippet for other in your answer)